# Why does the Health of the Enemy Stop Resetting

Tags: java, loops, oop

I'm recreating a text based dungeon RPG I made earlier using OOP, but ran into an issue. Below we have the class for the battle sequence. When entering in the inputs to attack and use health potions everything works as intended except for one thing. After defeating the first foe,  the health of the enemies stops resetting when a new one appears causing their health values to become negative. Why is that?

EDIT: I found a solution!

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    public class BattleSequence {
    
        public static void main(String args[]) {
    
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            Player player = new Player();
            Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
            Potion potion = new Potion();
            Random rand = new Random();
    
            System.out.println("Welcome to the dungeon!");
    
            enemy.randomEnemy = enemy.enemyType[rand.nextInt(enemy.enemyType.length)];
            System.out.println("# A " + enemy.randomEnemy + " appears! #");
    
    
            while (player.start == 0) {
                System.out.println("---------------------------");
                System.out.println("Your current health is " + player.playerHealth + ".");
                System.out.println("Your current attack damage is " + player.playerAttackDamage + ".");
                System.out.println("Your current level is " + player.playerLevel + ".");
                System.out.println("Your currently have " + player.playerHealthPotions + " health potions.");
                System.out.println("---------------------------");
    
                System.out.println("What would you like to do?\n");
                System.out.println("Type 1 to attack, 2 to use health potion, and 3 to run\n");
    
                String Input = input.nextLine();
                if (Input.equals("1")) {
                    System.out.println("---------------------------");
                    System.out.println("You strike the " + enemy.randomEnemy + " for " + player.playerAttackDamage + " damage.\n");
                    System.out.println("---------------------------");
                    enemy.enemyHealth -= player.playerAttackDamage;
                    if (enemy.enemyHealth >= player.playerAttackDamage) {
                        System.out.println("The " + enemy.randomEnemy + " has " + enemy.enemyHealth + " health remaining.\n");
                    }
                }
    
                 else if (Input.equals("2")) {
    
                    if (player.playerHealthPotions > 0) {
                        player.playerHealth += potion.potionHealAmount;
                        player.playerHealthPotions = player.playerHealthPotions - 1;
                        System.out.println("You drank a health potion healing you for " + potion.potionHealAmount + " health. You now have " + player.playerHealthPotions + " health potions remaining.\n");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("You have no more potions available, fight enemies for a chance to receive more.\n");
                    }
                }
                if (enemy.enemyHealth < 1) {
                    System.out.println("The " + enemy.randomEnemy + " has been defeated.\n");
                    enemy.randomEnemy = enemy.enemyType[rand.nextInt(enemy.enemyType.length)];
                    System.out.println("# A " + enemy.randomEnemy + " appears! #");
    
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("The " + enemy.randomEnemy + " strikes you for " + enemy.randomDamage + " damage.\n");
                    player.playerHealth -= enemy.randomDamage;
                }
    
    
    
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "stops resetting"? You never do anything to reset it. You only assign a new enemyType to the enemy. Why do you think the health would reset? What part of your code do you think would cause it to reset?

Comment: You should start thinking about creating methods in Enemy object to redefine a new Enemy like enemy.defeated() will assign a new Type and set the HP to the assigned Type HP. So you won't have a verbouse code and it will work fine everytimes. I think that setting a new type if Enemy like you do doesn't affect the HP attribute of it.

Comment: I recognize that and was just looking into it. However the reason why I was wondering about this is because the health values of enemies used to reset upon defeating an enemy but no longer does so. That led me to think that every new enemy would spawn with their values reset.

Comment: This is not oop code... Oop means encapsulation and object creation. For example, creating a new enemy object whenever you want a new enemy. Your problems stem from not following oop design principals. You need to reset your enemy hp manually.